# SQL escaping with the ESCAPE keyword - what if escape character appeared in the LIKE value

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, escaping, character

I am trying to escape `_` in my application by using `ESCAPE` keyword

If user entered: `A_1` I add `$` before the underscore so the final query is like this:

```
SELECT APPLICATION AS "APPLICATION"  
FROM  ALARM 
WHERE (((APPLICATION LIKE 'A$_1' ESCAPE '$')))
```

In my case the user can enter anything, what will happen if the user typed `$` in the original string?

I am using the `LIKE` keyword because I am using wild-card %, if user typed `*` i am translating it in the server to `%` to use it as wild card, other than that I don't wan't to use wild cards.

If user typed string with `_` I must search with `_` (no wildcard) same as `%`

For example if I have application called `A$` in my DB and user typed `$`, the query will be:

```
SELECT APPLICATION AS "APPLICATION"  
FROM  ALARM 
WHERE (((APPLICATION LIKE 'A$' ESCAPE '$')))
```

Will it take the value as `A$` in this case? 
In my query the ESCAPE character can be any in any position in the value and not necessarily in the end.

How I can deal with this situation for both MySQL and Oracle in the same query? 
Thanks

Comment: `like 'A$' escape '$'` will fail with *ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character*. But I'm not sure that could happen in the application you describe. Perhaps some more detailed examples would help clarify the issue.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson My Application create dynamic queries, based on the user input from the database, and show it to the user.

I don't want to query my database with any wild-card, wild cards is not valid in my application, so if the user enters string that contain _ for example I want to search for it.
My application work for PG, Mysql, Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is (as you used dynamic SQL) test the user input and generate two different queries

1) for input `*` (i.e. all application should be listed)

```
 WHERE  APPLICATION is not NULL
```

which is the same as `APPLICATION LIKE '%'` (you may ommit the `where` clause is the column is not nullable.

2) for other input, i.e. only the exact matching application should be selected use `=` and not `like`

```
 WHERE  APPLICATION = '{user input}'
```

without the need of escaping.

If you want to unify the query for some reason and use `LIKE` in both cases, you *must escape all wildcard characters* **and the escape character**.

To match the input `A$` change to `A$$`

To match the input `A$_%` change to `A$$$_$%`

For example

```
where  APPLICATION LIKE 'A$$$_$%' ESCAPE '$'
```

will match the string

```
A$_%
```

Comment: I set this answer because its the most well explained answer in the post.

Answer (score 0):

> *Will it take the value as A$ in this case?*

In such scenarios the easiest way is to check it by yourself:

```
-- MySQL
SELECT 'First', APPLICATION AS "APPLICATION"  
FROM  (SELECT 'A$' AS APPLICATION) ALARM   -- mocking data with inline view
WHERE (((APPLICATION LIKE 'A$' ESCAPE '$'))); 
-- will return a match


SELECT 'Second', APPLICATION AS "APPLICATION"  
FROM  (SELECT 'A$' AS APPLICATION) ALARM 
WHERE (((APPLICATION LIKE 'A$_' ESCAPE '$')));
-- 0 rows returned
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/FLAIVR48557)**

And Oracle:

```
SELECT APPLICATION AS "APPLICATION"  
FROM  (SELECT 'A$' AS APPLICATION FROM dual) ALARM
WHERE (((APPLICATION LIKE 'A$' ESCAPE '$')));
-- ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character


SELECT APPLICATION AS "APPLICATION"  
FROM  (SELECT 'A$' AS APPLICATION FROM dual) ALARM
WHERE (((APPLICATION LIKE 'A$_' ESCAPE '$')));
-- no rows selected
```

Comment: But in my query the escape character could be anywhere in the value and not only in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYESS WHERE ENAME LIKE '_@_%' ESCAPE '@';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it lacks explanation. Please consider adding text to explain what it does, and why it answers the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

> " I don't want to query my database with any wild-card, wild cards is not valid in my application"

If wildcards aren't valid in your application don't use the LIKE operator. You only need to escape underscores because you have a LIKE and underscores are a wildcard. Use equality operations and your problem literally disappears.

These WHERE clauses are equivalent:

```
where application like 'A$_1' escape '$'
where application = 'A_1'
```

Comment: I meant wild cards is not valid if typed as % or _ 

But if the user typed * we change it to % to be used as wild-card.

Sorry I think I should've explained more.

Comment: Then please **edit your question** to include sufficient information for us to understand your actual requirements.